# Get vuex action response object in component context

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get the response object resulting of calling a vuex action with axios, I need the response in my object but it says undefined for some reason.

In my component method:

```
mounted()
{
    console.log(this.$options.name+' component successfully mounted');
    this.$store.dispatch(this.module+'/'+this.action, this.payload)
    .then((response) => 
    { 
        console.log(response);
        this.items = response.data.data;
        this.pagination = response.data.pagination;

    });
},
```

My vuex action:

```
list({ commit }, payload)
    {
        commit( 'Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:1 }, { root: true });
        return axios.get('/api/posts', { params: payload })
        .then((response) => {
            commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:2, response:response }, { root: true });
            console.log(response);
            commit('SET_POSTS',  response.data.data.data );
            commit('SET_PAGINATION',  response.data.pagination );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:3, errors: error }, { root: true });
            throw error;
        });
    },
```

Using vuex state is not an option, I want to use the component data properties items and pagination instead.

Comment: The reason is that you don't return the value, so it's undefined. It's not common to return a value from an action because it's supposed to set values in store and that's what it does. You can add `return response` or read values from this.$store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `promise` to get the response in the component

```
list({ commit }, payload)
    {
        commit( 'Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:1 }, { root: true });
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          axios.get('/api/posts', { params: payload })
          .then((response) => {
              commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:2, response:response }, { root: true });  
              console.log(response);
              commit('SET_POSTS',  response.data.data.data );
              commit('SET_PAGINATION',  response.data.pagination );
              resolve(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', { status:3, errors: error }, { root: true });           reject(error);
              throw error;
          });
       })
    },
```

> Using `async`

```
async list({commit}, payload) {
    commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', {status: 1}, {root: true});
    try {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/posts', {params: payload});
        commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', {status: 2, response: response}, {root: true});
        console.log(response);
        commit('SET_POSTS', response.data.data.data);
        commit('SET_PAGINATION', response.data.pagination);
        return response;
    } catch (e) {
        commit('Loader/SET_LOADER', {status: 3, errors: error}, {root: true});
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is promise constructor antipattern. A promise is already returned, `return axios.get(,..)`

Comment: Have you tried this? Using `Promise` for returning the promises back to component is working way otherwise it is showing `undefined` in the component.

Comment: It is working but inefficient way. You forgot `reject`, it will stuck on error. It doesn't need to be tried to see what's going on. The code could be fixed with simple `return response`.

Comment: The `reject` is already there in the `catch` section. I forgot to format it.

Comment: @EstusFlask Adding the efficient solution will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I will be using your async code, looks really clean, thanks!